# Displaying mysql results on my website using datatables with dynamic headers

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, datatables

So i have a website that I am developing for work. It allows sales people to go in and enter a date range and their initials and it queries my database and returns the tables to them with their data. The amount of columns that I pull depends on the date range that they select. The longer the time period, the higher the number of columns (i separate it week by week so more days = mores weeks)

The problem I am having is that when i pull the column headers dynamically, using a for loop that grabs the headers from the mysql query so that it is dynamic and I dont have to code every case for every week they can choose, the headers replace the first item in my table so I lose 1 row.

I was wondering if anyone has any experience in grabbing the column headers of a mysql query set dynamically and using them with datatables?

I didn't want to paste a lot of code and cluster this post so let me know what you would like to see and I will provide it.

Thank you in advance for all the help and I hope I wasn't too confusing with what my problem is.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sampleTable";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
?>

<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fa fa-table"></i></div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="adminTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <?php
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        foreach(array_keys($result->fetch_assoc()) as $field){
                            echo "<th>" . $field . "</th>";
                        }
                        echo "</tr>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<h1 align=\"center\">No Results Found</h1>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            foreach ($data as $field => $value){
                                echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
                            }
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated yesterday at 11:59 PM</div>
</div>

<!--Not included in current file - included in base php-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": '55vh',
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging": false,
        dom: 'iftB',
        buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: You _need to_ show us the code. Are you getting everything (headers + body) in 1 query or are you doing it separately? I'd start with 2 separate queries and then combine them once you have it going.

Comment: @waterloomatt I posted the code and I am doing it in one query but I have tried it in two separate queries and it still yielded the same problem.

Comment: The generic term for this task is *pivoting* your tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the result of the first fetch into a variable, and then echo it before fetching the other rows:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="adminTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <?php
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    $firstRow = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    foreach(array_keys( $firstRow ) as $field){
                        echo "<th>" . $field . "</th>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                } else {
                    echo "<h1 align=\"center\">No Results Found</h1>";
                }
                ?>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        foreach ($firstRow as $field => $value){
                            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
                        }
                        echo "</tr>";

                    while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        foreach ($data as $field => $value){
                            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
                        }
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$result->fetch_assoc()` doesn't advance the resultset to the next row but you can manually trigger that by `$result->data_seek(2)`. Do this after outputting the header row.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

But again, you should probably break this up into 2 queries or have a flag in the result set which tells you whether this is a  header row or a body row.